# PowerShell V2 Stop screen resolution interfering

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a script which loads a .ps1 form. 
Issue at the moment is that my display is at 100%, but for some its 125%, 150%.

For the users that will mean that the screen text will be in a zoom state.
Is there a way to stop this from messing the form.
or is there a way to detect that the display is changed and re-apply the font size?

```html
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Sample Form"
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "This form is very simple."
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
    #  If a user is logged on, then get display scale factor for logged on user (even if running in session 0)
[boolean]$UserDisplayScaleFactor = $false
If ($RunAsActiveUser) {
    [int32]$dpiPixels = Get-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics' -Value 'AppliedDPI' -SID $RunAsActiveUser.SID
    If (-not ([string]$dpiPixels)) {
        [int32]$dpiPixels = Get-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop' -Value 'LogPixels' -SID $RunAsActiveUser.SID
    }
    [boolean]$UserDisplayScaleFactor = $true
}
If (-not ([string]$dpiPixels)) {
    #  This registry setting only exists if system scale factor has been changed at least once
    [int32]$dpiPixels = Get-RegistryKey -Key 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI' -Value 'LogPixels'
    [boolean]$UserDisplayScaleFactor = $false
}
Switch ($dpiPixels) {
    96 { [int32]$dpiScale = 100 }
    120 { [int32]$dpiScale = 125 }
    144 { [int32]$dpiScale = 150 }
    192 { [int32]$dpiScale = 200 }
    Default { [int32]$dpiScale = 100 }
}
```

Source: http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/ in the **AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1** file

Comment: cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name "LogPixels"

if($val.LogPixels -eq 120)
{
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",(8.25/1.25))
    $objForm.Font = $Font
}if($val.LogPixels -eq 150){
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",(8.25/1.50))
    $objForm.Font = $Font
}

Answer (score 0):

When I ran that Mr. Annoyed it gave me an error where it doesn't recognise the get-regkey term.

I did however come up with a different way to keep the fonts the same...

```html
cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name "LogPixels"

if($val.LogPixels -eq 120)
{
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",(8.25/1.25))
    $objForm.Font = $Font
}if($val.LogPixels -eq 150){
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",(8.25/1.50))
    $objForm.Font = $Font
}
```

Hope this helps people out, only this is that I had a web browser in the form and was unable to set the zoom functions, zoom in/out...